# How to configure MySQL document store on AWS RDS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, document-store, mysql-x-devapi

I am new to AWS RDS & MySQL document store.

I have created one lambda (NodeJS 4.3) & one RDS MySQL instance which is having default port 3306. I have enabled X Plugin as mentioned in this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store-setting-up.html) via MySQL shell and its successfully installed which is needed for MySQL document store.

My lambda imports [xdevapi (@mysql/xdevapi)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi) package and tries to connect with MySQL RDS instance on port 33060 because xdevapi uses 33060 as default port.

but when I tries to test my lambda then it is unable to connect. Because, [xdevapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi) uses default port 33060. But my MySQL default port is 3306. So, I added custom rule in security groups to allow inbound for port 33060. And then, I tried to test lambda then it still unable to connect.

Kindly, suggest if anything I am missing here.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is you can't use X Plugin in mysql RDS.

Read the section [MySQL Features Not Supported By Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html) in the official of AWS RDS it says that *X Plugin* is not supported that's why [RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html)  doesn't provide any provision to configure port for it.

*X Plugin* implements a different protocol called *X Protocol* for the communication so it needs to be exposed in different port (other than the mysql connection port), its default port is *33060*.
The connection url will be something like this `mysqlx://localhost:33060`.

I also had to use mysql Document Store so I installed mysql 8 on EC2 and it works well with their [X DevAPI](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/).

Comment: Surely this has got to be the accepted answer for this question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `getSession` method takes a `port` option:

```
xdevapi.getSession({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    dbUser: 'root',
    dbPassword: ''
})
```

Comment: @Shri.harry you need to be more specific than just to say "it didn't work."  Be specific.  It is impossible to connect to RDS on any port other than 3306, so this answer is *trying* to help you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a duplicate of this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789838/does-aws-rds-supports-mysql-as-document-store/50835289#50835289). Short answer is: you probably won't be able to use the MySQL Document Store on RDS. Check the linked thread for additional details.