# Does AWS RDS supports MySQL as document store

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, document-store

I am able to connect normal AWS RDS MySQL instance (5.7.16). But, as I have to use MySQL as document store, I have configured MySQL instance by installing mysqlx plugin, Which is required for document store.

After this, I am trying to connect MySQL document store on port 33060 on same instance but unable to connect. I am using lambda for connection which imports xdevapi (@mysql/xdevapi) package and tries to connect with MySQL RDS instance on port 33060.

But, there is no error which I can see for, therefore I am just wondering does AWS RDS has support for MySQL document store.

Code:

```
 xdevapi.getSession({
   host: process.env.HOSTNAME, 
   port:  process.env.PORT,
   dbUser: process.env.DB_USER, 
   dbPassword:  process.env.DB_PASSWORD
 }).then(function (session) {
    console.log("Connected");
    session.close();
    return callback(null, {'responsne':'connected', statusCode: 200});
 }).catch(function (err) {
     console.log(err.stack);
     return callback(null, {'responsne':err.stack, statusCode: 400});
 });
```

Kindly, help me out to find this.

Comment: If you can't see an error it means you must turn up the error reporting.

Comment: I am using .catch() to catch any errors. And I tried to give some unavailable port then I get error. But, this 33060 port I can't see anything and its not going inside if there is no problem. I will update question with my code.

Comment: Why are you using port 33060 instead of port 3306? Also, is that port (3306 or 33060) open in RDS Security group?

Answer (score 1):

Since MySQL 8.0.11 is now generally available on AWS, we've been looking at the Document Store functionality via x-plugin.

Following through the sample DB (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-shell-tutorial-javascript-download.html) it creates the schema and imports it OK, but doesn't seem to expose the db object to mysqlsh.

For example, when I run

```
\use world_x
```

connected to a local host instance it outputs

```
Default schema set to `world_x`.
Fetching table and column names from `world_x` for auto-completion... Press ^C to stop.
```

whereas when connected to an RDS instance I only get

```
Default schema set to `world_x`.
```

Additionally, according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.VersionMgmt the X Plugin isn't supported which, as I understand it, means Document Store functionality isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late answer, but hopefully it might help to clarify similar questions in the future. Since apparently RDS is running MySQL 5.7.16, it should not load the X Plugin (which enables the Document Store) by default.

Unless you are able to provide `mysqld` startup options (in this case `--plugin-load=mysqlx=mysql.so`) or have client access, in which case you can follow the steps described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/document-store-setting-up.html) to enable the plugin, you are out of luck.

There's also the possibility that RDS is running some kind of fork, which does not even bundle the X Plugin.

Also, the X DevAPI connector for Node.js only guarantees support for MySQL 8.0, so, although you should be able to use it with later MySQL 5.7 versions, there are a few limitations.