# mysqlx plugin unreachable on Amazon RDS (MySQL 8.0)

Tags: node.js, mysql-connector, mysql-8.0, mysql-x-devapi

Running local instances okay but have problem connecting to MySQL RDS AWS, not a connectivity issue to RDS private network.

> This is the error when attempting to make a connection. ERROR - Unable
> to sync database. Connection attempt to the server was aborted.
> Timeout of 10000 ms was exceeded.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM performance_schema.global_variables WHERE variable_name LIKE 'mysqlx%';
| VARIABLE_NAME | VARIABLE_VALUE |
```

> +| mysqlx_bind_address | *
> +| mysqlx_connect_timeout | 30
> +| mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout | 60
> +| mysqlx_max_allowed_packet | 1048576
> +| mysqlx_max_connections | 100
> +| mysqlx_min_worker_threads | 2
> +| mysqlx_port | 33060
> +| mysqlx_port_open_timeout | 0
>
> and the plugin is active as well, from sql, show plugins shows: mysqlx
> | ACTIVE | DAEMON | mysqlx.so | GPL |

Referencing to contributors on [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=308261).

Basing on this thread.
[Does AWS RDS supports MySQL as document store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789838/does-aws-rds-supports-mysql-as-document-store)
@ruiquelhas /Mr. Rui Quelhas seems to suggest there is a way to enable RDS running X-protocol based on the current MySQL RDS setup mentioned by others above.

My existing MySql RDS instance shows disablement of mysqlx.
[image]

Using MySql Community RDS 8.0.21 version on Node.Js with mysql/xdevapi 8.0.21.

RDS AWS seems to make mysqlx [parameters](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-modify-parameter-group-values/) non-modifiable on initiation of the database as shown.

[image]

However, they do allow installation of [new plugin](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-validate-password-plugin/) by using Mysql statement as shown

So we can't do this setting mysqlx=1 in my MySQL configuration file. Large portion of our application is written with mysqlx, hope someone can show us the workaround? [Google SQL doesn't support X Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/features).

Answer (score 1):

Kevin, sorry for the confusion but by the time that answer was written, Amazon RDS was based on a MySQL 5.7.x version, which doesn't come with the X Plugin installed by default. However, it doesn't mean you can't spin up MySQL 8.x and disable the X Plugin altogether, which seems to be the case.

According the Amazon RDS [user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.Features), X Plugin is not supported (that's why it is disabled). If you are looking for an alternative DBaaS, [MySQL Database Service](https://www.oracle.com/mysql/) on Oracle Cloud is probably the only equivalent alternative that supports it, as far as I can tell.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js